# Zonemta not connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: node.js, npm, connection

I'm using zonemta
when i open web-admin panel of zonemta show this error

> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

Anybody can help me?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ZoneMTA default API port have changed from 8080 to 12080. You can try to override the web-admin default config changing `apiServer` attribute to http://localhost:12080 and see if works.